# Does using scrapy-splash significantly affect scraping speed?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

So far, I have been using just scrapy and writing custom classes to deal with websites using ajax.

But if I were to use scrapy-splash, which from what I understand, scrapes the rendered html after javascript, will the speed of my crawler be affected significantly?

What would be the comparison between time it takes to scrape a vanilla html page with scrapy vs javascript rendered html with scrapy-splash?

And lastly, how do scrapy-splash and Selenium compare?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It depends on the amount of javascript present on the page.

You must know that to render all the javascript the splash **takes some time** and the python application proceeds without waiting for the rendering to be complete. So sometimes splash is also not able to do it.

- You can explicitly put a wait for rendering as it needs some time generally.
- Also it is a good practice to put up some `wait`.

Here,

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse, meta={'splash':{'args':{'wait':'25'},'endpoint':'render.html'}})
```

**or**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, endpoint='render.html',
        args={'wait': 5, 'html' : 1 } )
```

### Between scrapy and selenium

`Selenium` is only used to automate web browser interaction, `Scrapy` is used to download HTML, process data and save it(whole web crawling framework).

Talking about scraping I would recommend `scrapy` and if the problem is javascript.

- Scrapy already has its own official project for javascript called [scrapy-splash](https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-splash/)
- Also, you can create new instance of webdriver from Selenium in the  scrapy spider, do some work, extract the data, and then close it after all work done.

Comment: Thank you for answering @Nandesh! The question has been closed as broad, but your answer covered all the important points for me!

Comment: @mgrollins always :)