# Directly navigate to page without URL (BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm looking to navigate to a page that doesn't have a direct URL.

If you go to https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/tsla/option-chain and then set the month to May 2020 and the date to 05/08/2020, you will see the URL does not change.

Is there any way for me to use beautifulSoup to get the data for that particular date?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python selenium get data from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59241101/python-selenium-get-data-from-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this question that solves my issue.

[Scrape dynamic data using scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57573886/scrape-dynamic-data-using-scrapy)

https://api.nasdaq.com/api/quote/TSLA/option-chain?assetclass=stocks&todate=2020-05-08&fromdate=2020-05-08&limit=0